# Query using Spark SQL with array_contains yields no results

Tags: apache-spark-sql

Here is the schema I am working with (its a smaller dataframe from a larger schema)

```
root
 |-- NET: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- BDZ_BUNDLE_BIT: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- BDZ_BUNDLE_NAME: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
```

I want to query and filter the "name" element for a match. I have tried the following but it yields no result.

```
val report = df.select ("*").where(array_contains (df("NET.name"), "SCAN_INSIDE")).collect
```

Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

val report = df.select name where(array_contains(NET,'name you want to search').collect()